# Violations on USB connector in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, drc

I am designing a PCB and in the design, I am using a USB micro-B connector. I have experience in designing schematics but have recently started designing PCB layouts. I got this component from the SnapEda website and it gives me all these (in the picture below) rule violations. I don't exactly know how to resolve these violations and what some of them mean exactly. Help will be much appreciated.

[image: PCB layout of the connector]

[image: Violations]

[image: Violations]

Comment: FYI, if this is a standalone board (not in a metal enclosure), you almost certainly want shield tied hard to ground plane. Then vias in the pads (if it's acceptable for your soldering process) will improve strength slightly as well as providing a firm ground for the shield.

Answer (score 2):

Just looks like you've got the tracks assigned a different net (or no net) from the pads so Altium is telling you they are shorted.

If you placed those tracks, remove them and replace them starting from a pad. You could also manually reassign them or use Ctrl-H (but the latter is not a great idea in general).

You really should have sensible net names assigned by your schematic design. For example, NetC12_2 looks like it should be some kind of GND net.

---

wrt additional question, here is the method  of selection:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have noticed, that the pad was made out of two pads (one is a hole), one had the designator and the right net name and the other (the hole) didn't have a designator and didn't have a net name. So, I added a net name and it worked, but it gave me new errors and it says: Pad J2-S6 on multi-layer on Net NetC12-2. The warning is Unplated multi-layer pads detected.

Comment: That sounds like a very useful warning if that slot is actually unplated. You should check that out. It's not what you want.

Comment: I have never heard of that and have now searched on the internet what is the difference but have not found much information. What is the difference (except that it uses a different drill) and in what cases do we choose one over the other?

Comment: If you want unplated holes you specify that. Usually a separate drill file is generated. Typically you might only want unplated holes for something mechanical like a mounting hole or a hole for a snap-in plastic part. Something with pads on each side of the board and no plating looks (for good reason) suspicious to the software.